# How do I design pcb keypad contacts for hard gold plating

Tags: pcb-design, switches

Are there any special features that need to be added to the pcb footprint of membrane key contact in order to facilitate hard gold plating of the contact area?

In other words, how does the hard gold electroplating process actually work? Are separate contacts needed for the electroplating process?

Comment: Are you hoping to have this hard gold finish applied to *only* the key contacts, or to *all* exposed "copper" on the board as something like an ENIG finish would typically end up?   Generally the rule for anything atypical is "talk to your fab" to see *if* they can do it what you want, and then *how* they would like that represented in the design files.

Comment: I am wanting the hard gold to be only on the key contacts. Unfortunately I do not have a fab to talk to at this point. I was hoping there were some general principles for doing selective hard gold plating on a pcb

Comment: A little playing with a search engine suggests you want "*Selective* Hard Gold" and that this involves some extra labor in applying a mask (which you would have to generate) vs. some savings on material cost (and presumably not getting too much gold on types of pads where it might cause a solderability issue)

Comment: If I understand your response correctly, I would have to generate a mask that covered the whole pcb except the gold plated key contacts. To me, this implies a chemical plating process rather than an electroplating process, however I stand to be corrected on this. And then after the hard gold plating, I assume they would have to masked off to be able to do an ENIG finish on the rest of the board.

Answer (score 1):

Just make an additional Gerber layer that exposes just the button contact regions.

Next you describe that layer in your fab drawing and fab notes documentation what that layer is for along with all your other layers.

Almost all PCB fab houses can take it from there it adapt to their hard gold process. That may mean they invert the supplied Gerber in terms of negative or positive image and over or under size the features as needed.

By the way...your comment about not having a fab house to talk to is silly. Pick out one or two and contact them for more specific details about how you can make the Gerber layer most useful to them for their process.